# download the PDF file inside the .GZ compress file in php

Tags: php, pdf, gzip, php-5.2

I have .gz compress file binary64 decoded code, I want to uncompressed this and download the PDF file inside the compress file. please give me an idea for this.

I did something like this...

```
function getShopmateInvoicePDF($documentName,$fileName,$base64binary){
     header('Content-Type: application/gzip');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.trim($fileName).'"');
     print $base64binary;
}
```

I tried `$base64binary = gzuncompress($base64binary)`

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.trim($documentName).'.pdf"');
print base64binary;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

```
 $g=tempnam('/tmp','ff');
 @file_put_contents($g,$base64binary);
 ob_start();
 readgzfile($g);
 $d=ob_get_clean();
 return $d;
```